# ng-blur is not called from a function triggered by ng-keyup

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

so I have a ng-blur function that correctly fires if I do this

```
  $scope.disableReturnButton = function($event){
    document.onkeyup=function(e) {

        if(e.which == 13){

          $event.target.blur();
          return false;
        }
    }
  }
```

however if I try to set the keyup event on the element only, it doesn't seem to trigger ng-blur when the blur event happens

```
  $scope.disableReturnButton = function($event){

    if($event.which == 13){
      $event.target.blur();// this blurs the element but doesn't trigger the ng-blur
      return false;
    }

  }
```

here's the markup

```
<span contenteditable="true" class="blanks" 
  ng-blur="blurredWhy($event)"
  ng-focus="focusedWhy($event)" 
  ng-bind="data.why" 
  ng-keyup="disableReturnButton($event)"></span>
```

Comment: You may need wrap the `$event.target.blur()` in an `$apply` just a thought.  Looking at it, I would think what you have should work.

Comment: i think this is the right behaviour. if you, for example, change a $scope variable (which is bound to any element in your DOM) via code, it's elements ng-change method will not fire too. anyway, you can add more then one function: 'ng-keyup="fnOne();fnTwo()"' but you will get another $event object

Answer (score 0):

If you use `return false;` in the event handler, with jQuery it will stop propagation and stop other events from firing in the chain. Since Angular uses jQuery lite (or you have jQuery full as well on the page) returning false will kill upstream events.

The first example would work because it uses the document.onkeyup which registers the event listener outside of jQuery.

See [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: I tried using event.preventDefault(), but that also seems to stop the blur event from firing.

Comment: You shouldn't do either if you want the events to propagate.

Comment: is there a way then to prevent the carriage return but still allow the other events to propogate?

Comment: If the enter key is found, then perhaps you can manually trigger the scope methods that you wish to fire, pass the same $event value to them, and return false.